# Is positive integrable function, pointwise limit of increasing smooth compacly support functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let assume $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be a bounded domain. It is well-known that if $ f \in L^1(U) $ and $ f \geq 0 $, then there exists a sequence of $C_0^{\infty}(U)$ functions like $ \{ f_n \} $, such that

$$ f_n \to f \quad \mathrm{in} \,\, L^1(U) $$

> **My question is this: Can I also consider that the sequnce $\{ f_n \} $ of smooth compactly support functions are increasing:** 
>   $$ f_n(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x) \leq f(x) \quad \forall x \in U $$
>   **and the above theorem remains correct.**

Answer (score 2):

Example: let $B\subset U$ be compact, nowhere dense in $U$ but of positive Lebesgue measure. Let $f=1$ on $B$ and $0$ on $U\setminus B$. Any   non-negative function in $C_0^\infty(U)$ that is dominated by $f$ is identically $0$ on $U$. Thus $f_n(x)\uparrow f(x)$ cannot hold at any point of $B$. In particular, if $f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x)\le f(x)$, $\forall n, \forall x\in U$ (with $f_n\in C^\infty_0(U)$) then  $f_n$ cannot converge to $f$ in $L^1(U)$.